# This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8

Tags: android, adt

I have been working with Android Developer Tool since long time without issue.Recently I updated my ADT and now I am unable to create a simple activity by (**New->Other->Android Activity**).It is providing only option to create Action bar Activity.

**So How to create simple activity with layout**
[image]

My ADT version is **22.6**

Answer (score 1):

**Why is this happening**
The template that you are trying to add uses features (like the actionbar) that requires an API level higher than 14, in the first step of the wizard, you selected 9. And since 9 < 14 you get this error.

**What can I do**

- Chose an higher minimum API level (at least 14 for this template). Go back to the first step and change the minimum api level.
- Chose a different template that is more compatible, by going back one step and select the most basic template.

**Which should I pick**
If you think it doesn't matter to use an api level higher than 14 (so your device won't work on pre-ice cream sandwich devices), you should definitely take the first option. If you don't mind using a more basic-UI template to start with, and you really require your app to work on pre-ice cream sandwich devices. You should pick the second option.

**What if I want both**
You could use a support library, this way you can enjoy API level 14+ features on pre API 14 devices. Some consider it  more difficult to setup & use though. https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html there are also samples available.

EDIT: In step below, you can select the kind of template:, notice the checkmark "create Activity", just uncheck it.
[image]

Comment: I am asking about ADT issue ..It dosen't matter whether I choose API 14+ or not ..IDE is not showing me option of template which supports lower version or creating a simple activity.

Comment: in fact it does, you currently selected "flow" (contains actionbar and fragments) and you should chose a more basic template.

Answer (score 1):

When you create project then you must set options: min SDK, target SDK and Compile With.
You can set min SDK to 10, target SDK to 10, but "Compile with" set to API 14.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this irritation would be to set the API level to 14, create the new activity, and then change the API level back to what you want it to be.  This seems to be an issue with this version of ADT and the new Activity creation wizard.

This used to work before, but I recently updated ADT and now I'm seeing issues on projects I haven't changed.

I've been doing this to create new activities and haven't seen any problems yet.